# How can I install Linux headers?

Tags: apt, kernel, linux-headers

I'm trying to install Linux headers in my system using `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)` command. When I run it, it gives me the below error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.10.10
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.10.10'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.10.10'
```

To solve this, I upgrade the system and reboot it. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unsupported `5.10.10` kernel.

You can't get Linux headers from Ubuntu repositories for this kernel. You should get the headers from the place you got the kernel image.

Comment: Oh, great. Finally *someone* at least has an explanation. Now, all I have to do is time travel back to many years ago to see where I got the install image for the old server I'm trying to salvage. No problem, I'll just do that. I'm sure me from the past will remember, when I see him. Thanks. Man, linux is such a *totally* great system.